# How can I make a search box with suggestions?

Tags: java

I want to have a search box for my java application which has suggestions as you type. As I have it right now, it only gives results after you press the button to search, but I want to have it just like the youtube website where it comes up with suggestions as you type. The problem is that with how slow the api requests are, it isn't possible to make a request for each new character entered into the search box. Here's the code for searching (There should be five suggestions shown):

```
private SearchListResponse search(String query)
{
        try
        {
            YouTube.Search.List request = youtube.search().list("snippet").setKey(API_KEY);
            SearchListResponse response = request.setMaxResults(5L).setQ(query).setType("video").execute();
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

And here's the basic search box I have right now:

```
    JTextField searchBox = new JTextField(20);
    container.add(searchBox);
    
    JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
    searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            search(searchBox.getText());
        }
    });
    container.add(searchButton);
```

Comment: If you can't do what you want to do what do you want us to say? You could keep a history of past searches and use a regex match against that but that's about it.

Comment: This isn't something that can be answered readily on this site, but you can find lots of long discussions on the web and in books that will suit your needs. Look into radix trees. Assuming you do want the search to be smart, like YouTube, you're going to have to come up with a list of searchable terms, assign them weights, and figure out an architecture that offers reasonable performance for the hardware you have available to you. Google has entire server farms dedicated to nothing but populating those smart search boxes, so this task might be more complex than you imagined.

Comment: *it isn't possible to make a request for each new character entered into the search box.* - add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field. You will be notified every time a character is added or removed and you can do your processing. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for an example to get you started.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "auto complete"